# Получить значение по формуле Google sheets в Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Как получить результат вычисления формулы в Google Apps script не вводя формулу в ячейку

Comment: Формула - это набор каких-то действий с данными. Вы можете большинство формул посчитать через gas. Например сумму диапазона. Просто считываете весь диапазон, суммируете его и получаете результат

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

Вероятно, вы имеете ввиду, существует ли некий процессор для вычисления формул вне Таблиц. Для Google Spreadsheets такого нет.

Есть нечто универсальное, но заточено под Excel https://github.com/formulajs/formulajs

Работает в Google Apps Script с парой костылей. Туда еще придется добавить пару палок и соплей, без этого работать толком не будет.

Другим вариантом может быть приложение, которое на базе внешней Таблицы получает данные, пересчитывает их и возвращает результат в текущую.